# AJV: property check. Two properties must be different between them

Tags: ajv

By using `ajv`, how can I reference `foo` to validate that `bar` has different value?

I've tried this:

```
"schema": {
       "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
       "type": "object",
       "required": [ "foo", "bar" ],
       "properties": {
           "foo": {
               "type": "string",
               "const": { "$data": "1/bar" },
               "errMessages": {
                    "required": "form.myForm.foo.required"
                }
           },
           "bar": {
                "type": "string",
                "not": {
                    "$data": "1/foo" 
                },
                "errMessages": {
                    "required": "form.myForm.bar.required"
                }
           }
       }
   }
```

I've tried also this combination:

```
  "foo": {
       "type": "string",
       "not" {
           "const": { "$data": "1/bar" },
       }
       ...
  }
```

And I see this message:

```
must be equal to constant
```

It looks like a solution... But then when you change them, the message still appears.
Any ideas?

But with no luck...